# Using a Gamepad To Control Any iOS Device?

Tags: ios, games

Gaming has taken on a whole new dimension since the introduction of the iPhone & definitely the iPad. Whilst these two Apple devices are great gaming devices, alot of games still try to emulate gamepads with onscreen buttons that are not so great.

Is there an App that will turn a gamepad eg an XBox 360 or Playstation gamepad into a controller for any game with touchscreen buttons & How to configure it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to use a PS3 controller on a jailbroken iPhone. You need the $7 app Blutrol and the SixpairTool for MacOS X. Before I rewrite the instructions, please simply refer to http://lifehacker.com/5991266/how-to-use-a-gamepad-for-any-ios-game-not-just-emulators.

## EDIT: In a nutshell

GETTING READY:

First, you need an jailbreak your iOS device. Then, download the App ***Blutrol*** (http://apt.thebigboss.org/mobileweb/onepackage.php?bundleid=ch.ringwald.blutrol&db=), which currently costs $6.99. In order to use the PS3 controller, you will need an additional app for MacOS: SixPairMac ([ringwald.ch/cydia/blutrol/SixPairMac-v1.0.zip](http://ringwald.ch/cydia/blutrol/SixPairMac-v1.0.zip))

SETUP for PS3 controllers:
Connect the PS3 controller via USB Cable, and the iOS device (via lightning cable or 30-pin cable) to your Mac. Click the button "Pair Controller to iPad" in SixPairMac. Now, open Blutrol on your iOS device and select the PS3 controller.

Comment: That looks interesting, if its possible to summarize, just in case the link you have given disappears

Comment: Nice one.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is not possible without a jailbreak.

However, projects like [this one](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/games/the-coco-controller) and [this one](http://www.icontrolpad.com/) deliver physical gaming buttons to your iPhone. They are still in development however.

Comment: I agree its looks like you have to jailbreak first. I think the two controllers you mention are just the tip of the iceberg & iOS gaming is only going to get better & better.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be possible. Every individual game developer is responsible for developing their own unique code for how they interact (or don't interact) with external accessories. Beyond that any third-party controller would need to connect via a specific Bluetooth stack to make them compatible with iOS devices (something that Microsoft and Sony most certainly have not done).

While I understand your desire and sentiment, this is not going to work. There are a few device makers that have made physical buttons to overlay on the screen and Bluetooth gaming controllers. However, even these devices have spotty support in games.

Answer (score -1):

Jailbreak your device and get blutrol on cydia with you Xbox controller:)
If on IPad mini put you controller on screen go to lock screen and click the game you want to play the controller on:)